# Lazy Loading in EF6 not populating related list of entities in a POCO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lazy-loading, prism-5

We are using code first approach to existing database. ORM is EF6 in our application we also use PRISM 5.0. Problem appears after passing object as a parameter to other view model with use of RequestNavigate method.

Our objects:

```
[Table("Pracownicy")]
public partial class Pracownicy
{
  ///...
  public string Name {get; set;}

  public virtual ICollection<KartyRCP> KartyRCP { get; set; }

  ///...
}

[Table("KartyRCP")]
public partial class KartyRCP
{
  ///...
  public string Numer {get; set;}

  ///...
}
```

We receive the object of Pracownicy in OnNavigatedTo method passed.

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    if (Worker == null && navigationContext.Parameters["pracownik"] != null)
    {
       Worker = (Pracownicy)navigationContext.Parameters["pracownik"];

       if (Worker != null)
       {
           WorkerPhoto = Worker.Photo;
                UpdateWorkAbsencesList();                                                                          
       }
    }   
}
```

In this ViewModel we reference Pracownicy POCO [NotMapped] property which queries the related KartyRCP entities (which is one to many relation with KartyRCP (Worker.KartyRCP)).

```
[NotMapped]
public string AktualnaKartaRCP
{
   get
    {
        if (aktualnaKartaRCP == null)
        {                    
            aktualnaKartaRCP = this.KartyRCP.Where(z => z.OkresFrom <= DateTime.Today && z.OkresTo >= DateTime.Today).Select(x => x.Numer).FirstOrDefault();
            if(aktualnaKartaRCP != null)
              aktualnaKartaRCP = aktualnaKartaRCP.TrimStart('0');                    
        }
        return aktualnaKartaRCP;
    }
 }
```

When we display first instance of Pracownicy the result is as expected - one of the KartyRCP is selected.
But when we try to display another instance of Pracownicy the AktualnaKartaRCP property returns null.  That's because the KartyRCP is not populated with data and contains 0 items, even though they exists in the database.
It is even stranger that if we try to open the same instance Pracownicy again, KartyRCP are getting populated.

We are not sure why lazy loading not populating related entities when quering from inside POCO class.

We found two workarounds first is to ask for list from a view model, which populates KartyRCP with data.: `var WorkAroundGetList = Worker.KartyRCP;`. Other workaround is to include table to be eagerly loaded with Pracownicy using include statement: `.Include(z => z.KartyRCP)`

But we are not pleased with such solutions. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On your context constructor for your database you need to enable lazy loading as it is turned off by default;

```
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("MyDbContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this not solve our problem, and we tried this earlier. But thanks for interest.

Comment: Lazy Loading is turned ON by default.